# What to do when an actively maintained package requires an obsolete package?

Tags: packages, warnings, obsolete

I've recently requested the IT guys to upgrade my texlive version to 2018, and now I noticed that it always throws a warning:

> Package remreset Warning: The remreset package is obsolete: (remreset)                \@removefomresset is defined.

Since I've never even heard about `remreset` before, I found this to be a bit confusing. Upon a bit of digging up, I figured out that `aliascnt` is where the fault lies. And since I use this quite often in my documents, I see this warning being thrown at me constantly when I compile things here at the office.

What can I do about this warning? What *should* I do about this warning?

Since downgrading/upgrading things requires hassling the IT guys, my preference is to minimize the amount of emails I need to send to them about the topic.

(Let me also say that I have an immense difficulty ignoring warnings when I compile things, so this one little warning is likely to drive me crazy until it's gone.)

Comment: I'm really not sure about these tags, though.

Comment: Add an issue here: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek.

Comment: This doesn't help with your problem, but just to give a bit of background: the `\@re­move­from­re­set` command provided by `remreset` is now provided by the LaTeX kernel, which is why `remreset` is now obsolete.

Comment: With the 2018 release the packages `remreset` amd `chngcntr` have been integrated into the LaTeX kernel. One should hope that Heiko updates `aliascnt`. For the moment, though, I believe you may ignore the warnings.

Comment: Step one would be to tell the maintainers of the package about it https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek. After they fix it, you would probably ask your IT department to update your TeX live again. But there are ways to suppress harmless warnings like these. You could say `\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{remreset}{The remreset package is obsolete}` before you load `aliascnt`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't have a github account.

Comment: @campa: "I believe you may ignore the warnings" is a very innocent sentence that is easy to say to someone like me. Kind of like "Just go and talk to her" or "Just call them and get that job that you want"...

Comment: Then you ask someone if he/she can add the issue (btw: I already informed David.)  And you really can ignore the warning.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me: I meant that no harm would come from these warnings (some other warnings should not be ignored so lightheartedly). But I agree that they can be unnerving, and egreg suggested a way to get rid of them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: If you already informed David, I see no point asking about that. Thanks!

Comment: I added an issue so that it doesn't get lost.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. I guess I should wait for [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) to show up here and say something about it. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will try to get me to fix it https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45398229#45398229

Comment: As an aside, perhaps you should have a local TeX installation. I wouldn't achieve much if I asked every piece of software to be installed by IT...

Comment: @KubaOber: That's not going to be possible. Not to mention, that I don't need that many software anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you are reassured that the specific warning is innocuous and will be most likely fixed in the near future, you can silence the warning: add

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{remreset}{The remreset package}
```

at the very top of your document.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

will produce the following console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/aliascnt.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty

Package remreset Warning: The remreset package is obsolete:
(remreset)                \@removefomresset is defined.

))
No file test.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10450 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Instead

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{remreset}{The remreset package}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

will produce

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/silence/silence.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/aliascnt.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty))
(./test.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdft
ex.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10450 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Is there a way to add this to *all* my document without actually adding it to any of my documents? Like some local tex config?

Comment: @Inkblot I'm afraid not. I'd simply ignore the warning: it is temporary and will disappear soon.

Comment: So... like a toothache. I guess it will have to do. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Inkblot if you have toothache, you go see a dentist. that is not to be ignored! ignoring these warnings however (which can be compared to imprints on plastic coffee lids stating the obvious "Content is hot") won't kill you or harm anyone. it will - if at all - only mess up your PDF output. therefore ignoring the warnings, stating a package as obsolete is okay.

Comment: This code could be added to the documentclass, which would save adding it to every document...?

Comment: @cmhughes It would defeat the purpose of the warning

Comment: @cmhughes it depends where the warning is generated.  If you can make your documentclass load the `silence` package and execute the `\warningfilter` macro *before* you run the code that produces the warning, that would be fine - but often, you can't do that. Putting `\RequirePackage` and `\warningfilter` *before* `\documentclass` in your input file guarantees things happen in the right order.

Comment: @naphaneal: I ignored toothaches for the better part of my life, and it's fine. Not to mention, that I did come to the LaTeX doctors. I'm pretty sure egreg is a doctor of philosophy.